# Is there any way to solve the ConfirmEmailAsync(TUser user, string token) NullReferenceException while using Amazon.AspNetCore.Identity.Cognito?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-cognito, nullreferenceexception

I am using Amazon.AspNetCore.Identity.Cognito and while using "ConfirmEmailAsync(TUser user, string token)" of UserManager, I am getting the NullReferenceException.

The Screenshot is provided:
[image: The Error]

The Code I did:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Confirm")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Confirm_Post(ConfirmModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if(user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("NotFound", "A user with given email address was not found");
        }

        var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, model.Code).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if(result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(var item in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(item.Code, item.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to solve this, as I am new to AWS, it seems puzzling.

Comment: It would be better if you provided your code as a text (click ? in the editor to get help how to add a code) instead of the screenshot. This would allow the others to test or modify it.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMacej, the code is now added as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I get a solution, now it no more causes the exception.
I use **ConfirmSignUpAsync(TUser user, string confirmationCode, bool forcedAliasCreation)** method instead of **ConfirmEmailAsync(TUser user, string token)** and it works!!

```
var result = await ((CognitoUserManager<CognitoUser>)_userManager).ConfirmSignUpAsync(user, model.Code, true);
if(result.Succeeded)
{
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The code is shared below, and if anyone finds it helpful, it'd be a pleasure.
Thanks all!!

Comment: I have stumbled across the same issue and your solution works. Thanks. However, this is sounds like bad design because it does not play nice with DI since the method requires a specific type rather than the one obtained through DI. Let's hope that they will fix this in a future version of `Amazon.AspNetCore.Identity.Cognito`.